# Rails 3 Conditional Validation (credit cards): Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, e-commerce

Seems odd, seems right?

```
validates_presence_of [:visa, :mc, :discover, :amex], :if => :credit_card => true
```

Any input is appreciated, getting a syntax error in the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
validates :visa, :mc, :discover, :amex, :presence => true, :if => :credit_card?
```

if credit card is a boolean field.

else define a method

```
def credit_card?
    credit_card.present?
end
```

Comment: Interesting @Cage, I agree with your attempt here. Weird weird thing is, all these attributes ARE boolean. Note that I'm using a tableless model, will that have any effect?

Comment: Woops and meant to say the error msg now is undefined method 'credit_card?' The boolean is definitely functioning as it should, because when I submit the form the values come up as zeroes and ones.

Comment: as I stated before the attributes are boolean, not working without the method, not working with the method. Thoughts?

Comment: are you still getting the errors or validations not working properly?

Comment: No errors, the worst part :( Just in the email the user/customer service receives, everything is still showing up. Ie, if you click JUST Visa, all 4 will show up (visa mc discover and amex).

Comment: One of the devs suggested using Jquery, but this way seems easier and more semantic.

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is in the template itself. Does this syntax look ok for the credit card/check stuff? https://gist.github.com/2660368

Comment: I think the underlying issue here is that I'm not using ActiveRecord, but ActiveModel.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it with the proc

```
validates :visa, :mc, :discover, :amex, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new{|model| model.credit_card.present?}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yuriy, but that did not do the trick unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, that was a pain though. And not perfect by any means. Next step would be so the user can only select credit card or check. Jquery?

model.rb

```
validate :check_if_at_least_one_credit_card, :if => "credit_card=='1'"
validate :check_if_check_is_clicked, :if => "check=='1'"

private

  def check_if_at_least_one_credit_card
    unless mc=="1" || visa=="1" || amex=="1" || discover=="1"
      errors.add(:base, "You need to choose at least one credit card type")
    end
  end

  def check_if_check_is_clicked
    unless check=="1"
      errors.add(:base, "You need to choose check or credit card")
    end
  end
```

Then this needs some cleaning up in but working as intended.

template.html.haml

```
%p{ :style => "font-size: 13px; color: #848687;" }= @bulk_order.check=="1" ? 'Check' : ''
%p{ :style => "font-size: 13px; color: #848687;" }= @bulk_order.credit_card=="1" ? 'Credit Card' : ''
%ul
  %li{ :style => "font-size: 13px; color: #848687;" }= @bulk_order.discover=="1" ? 'Discover' : ''
  %li{ :style => "font-size: 13px; color: #848687;" }= @bulk_order.amex=="1" ? 'American Express' : ''
  %li{ :style => "font-size: 13px; color: #848687;" }= @bulk_order.mc=="1" ? 'Mastercard' : ''
  %li{ :style => "font-size: 13px; color: #848687;" }= @bulk_order.visa=="1" ? 'Visa' : ''
```